# Find the essential bandwidth of rect function? i want the ans by using Energy spectral density and then essential bandwidth...

Tags: digital-communications

I am trying to find EBW of rect function but i am unable to solve the integral
after finding the fourier transform and then apply parseval's theorem?

Comment: What you did so far?

Comment: What is the essential bandwidth? Is this the same as the Gabor bandwidth?